# Apache configured as mpm_worker - why it still shows as mpm_prefork?

Tags: ubuntu, php-fpm, apache-2.4, mpm-prefork, mpm-worker

I believe that I properly configured Apache MPM as worker under Ubuntu 13.10, including PHP-FPM and FCGI, and disabled mod_php. When I run **top** I can clearly see multiple Apache (~2-3 MB) and php (~ 25-30 MB) processes running, which increase with users/requests.

Now, what is puzzling me is that when I check with **a2query -M** returns:

`prefork`

Or with **apachectl -V** :

```
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
```

Is this OK? Or did I miss something along the setup?

Comment: You forgot to explain what you did.

Comment: Installed mpm-worker, fcgi and fpm, configured apache to use fcgi handler,  disabled old php module, restarted everything and here I am. Everything is working, except this uncertainty.

Answer (score 0):

Given the lack of information in the question, there is some guessing going on here. Assuming Apache 2.4 install from Ubuntu repository where standard MPM's are included with the install, it would appear that you just need to "switch" from `prefork` to `worker`. **NOTE: You can ONLY start Apache with a single MPM selected, i.e. you MUST "dismod" the current MPM and then "enmod" the desired MPM**.

If so, the switch is made with the following commands:

```
 a2dismod mpm_prefork
 a2enmod mpm_worker
 service apache2 restart
```

To check the configuration BEFORE running the `service apache2 restart` command, you can use `apache2ctl -t`.

NOTE ALSO: If you are not logged in as root (and you should NOT be!), you will probably need to preface each command line with `sudo` to have sufficient privileges.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Colt, however, I have moved to a different server and different environment/hosting since then and I am not able to verify/check this anymore. Here everything is fine now.